# How to pass an image url to firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am able to pass the name, address, password, and email, but the url is "", how can I pass the image url next to the email and address data? If anyone can help, I would appreciate it very much !! I have a class called User Model and a SignUp.

```
String userImageUrl = "";
  static final String userAvatarUrl = 'url';
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  PickedFile _imageFile;
  
 if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
                      //  "uid": model.firebaseUser.uid,
                      "name": _nameController.text,
                      "email": _emailController.text,
                      "address": _addressController.text,
                      "url": userImageUrl,
                    };

                    model.signUp(
                      userData: userData,
                      pass: _passController.text,
                      onSucess: _onSucess,
                      onFail: _onFail,
                    );
                  }
                  uploadAndSaveImage();
                  uploadToStorage();

Future uploadToStorage() async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (c) {
          return LoadingAlertDialog(
            message: "Autentificando, Por favor espere...",
          );
        });

    String imageFileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imageFileName);
    UploadTask task = reference.putFile(File(_imageFile.path));

    await (await task).ref.getDownloadURL().then((urlImage) {
      urlImage = userImageUrl;


    class UserModel extends Model {
        Future<Null> _saveUserData(Map<String, dynamic> userData) async {
        this.userData = userData;
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
            .set(userData);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't link out to code, but make sure the minimal code to reproduce the problem is inside your question. If the code of your app is too big for that, read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to get a standalone repro.

Comment: Okay, now I just put in the code that I thought was necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Is your issue that the value is not appearing in Firebase since it's blank?

Comment: There in the firestore is: the name, address, email and the url: "", the url is just in quotes as I stated it at the beginning. I don't understand why ... I already managed to obtain the url separately but along with the name and email in Map userData it will not go at all.